# Form_for helpers - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I have a form right now that has 4 text_fields and only the bottom one actually adds the data to the model? All the text_fields are identical and for the life of me I can't figure out why they all don't work the same. Here is my code hopefully someone will have any easy answer?

```
class ResponsesController < ApplicationController

def new
@response = Response.new
end

def create
@response = Response.new(response_params)
if @response.save
  flash[:notice] = "Response has been edited"
  redirect_to new_response_path(:response)
else
  render "new"
end
 end

private

def response_params
params.require(:response).permit(:message)
end
```

this is my view

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Edit The Bounce Back Response</h3>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 well">
     <%= form_for @response do |form| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :message, "Visitor:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Visitor Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :message, "Staff:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Staff Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :message, "Volunteeer:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Volunteer Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :message, "Dance:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Dance Response!" %>
       </div>
      <%= form.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

[image]

If You type in the bottom text field it will actually input the data to message, if you use any other text field my console return is this

[image]

Comment: can u post your `responses_controller.rb` file?

Comment: where is your `edit and update` methods ? also is your form_for is located in `_form.html.erb` ?

Comment: I'm not there yet, I just want they text_field to input the data to the model

Comment: @but u r trying to update it. u should create update method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have the form submitting to :message everytime. So when the form is being submitted it is posting every field to params[:message] and so only the last one is actually being posted.

Edit:

For instance if I have a form for posts:

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  .input-title
    = f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title", required: true
  .input-content
    = f.text_area :content, class: 'ckeditor', required: true
  .input-submit
    = f.submit
```

It is written in haml but it is nearly identical. You can see that my text_field is for the title and my body is just named content.

In the controller I would create strong params

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

      def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params) # this is where the params are saved
    @post.forum_id = params[:forum_id]
    if @post.save
      usercount = current_user
      usercount.post_count += 1
      usercount.save
      redirect_to forum_posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

      private

      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content) # this is permitting what can be saved from the form
      end
```

Comment: I agree but how do I fix it?

Comment: Instead of :message you could just change them to be what describes them.

Comment: Message does describe it I want all of them to post to message because Eventually Each will belong to a different group depending on which field the user selects

Comment: Post your controller that saves the data. You can create strong params and permit them to be saved within the controller on submit

Comment: The form is POSTed at the same time, so having them all saved as one parameter doesn't work. Only the last parameter is actually posted to the route. Sorry for the barrage of comments and not as clear post. I was using one arm because kids were throwing fits. I'll edit the post to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. As i understand you want to update that fields. It should help you.

```
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Edit The Bounce Back Response</h3>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 well">
     <%= form_for @response do |form| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :message, "Visitor:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Visitor Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :staff, "Staff:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :staff, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Staff Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :volunteer, "Volunteeer:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :volunteer, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Volunteer Response!" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :dance, "Dance:", class: "response_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :dance, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Change Dance Response!" %>
       </div>
      <%= form.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

In Controller Update Strong Params

```
def response_params
    params.require(:response).permit(:message, :staff, :volunteer, :dance)
end
```